# Create custom workflows at item level

Tags: 2010, workflow

I want to users to create a workflow at the item level. That is when they create an item in a list/library they should be able to define a workflow, consisting of tasks and approval process. All this must happen within the browser. And each workflow in the list could be different. Ofcourse there are predefined actors and actions in the workflow but the process can take any route before completion.

Are there any tools available for such tasks. I have gone through [K2 Workflows](http://www.k2.com/en/sharepoint2010.aspx) but I doubt it will work for item level workflow building. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through SharePoint Designer. Users would not define the workflow, as much as they would be defining the variables in that workflow. If recipient users of these tasks and approval processes are what they need to define, then that is possible.

You need to start off with SharePoint Designer workflows. Here is an article of what SharePoint Designer workflows can accomplish for you: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx?CTT=3

Answer (score 0):

Nitin.

I am not 100% sure, but I think there is no possibility to create different workflows at items level. Possibly, you have to create item which has different fields like:

- Approvers;
- TypeOfWorkflow.

These fields should be filled in before starting a workflow, and workflow should read its value and choose the route and approvers based on it.